# Sort across multiple fields?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Is there a way to do a sort across multiple fields? e.g. sort by `last_edited` and `_id` timestamps? Essentially I need to sort on across both fields as if they were a single field. So the compound index doesn't seem to apply in this situation.

e.g.

For index: `{ a: 1, b: 1 }`:

mongo returns:

`[{ a: 1, b: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 4 }, { a: 2, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 3 }]`

while I need it to return:

`[{ a: 1, b: 1 }, { a: 2, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 3 }, { a: 1, b: 4 }]`

Sorted in ascending order in which the field with the greater value supersedes the other field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using aggregation framework, but you won't be able to use indexes an it is a rather brute force solution.

```
db.foo.aggregate(
    {$project: {a: 1, b: 1, sortKey: {$cond: [{$gt: ["$a", "$b"]}, "$a", "$b"]}}},
    {$sort: {sortKey: 1}},
    {$project: {a: 1, b: 1}}
)
```

If your collection is to big to be handled by aggregation similar thing can be achieved usgin map-reduce.

Comment: Does that fetch all documents then pick the greater field in memory and and then sort by that? Would it perform the same or worse than having a single, combined field to sort on from document creation?

Comment: Definitely worse. Having combined and indexed field is the best solution here.

Comment: I guess I'll just generate a timestamp at creation and for future edits on an `updated` field and sort on it.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. If you have collection a with documentes

```
{_id : 5, last_edited : 7}
{_id : 4, last_edited : 1}
{_id : 9, last_edited : 7}
{_id : 3, last_edited : 1}
{_id : 6, last_edited : 1}
```

You can sort this by two field (order matters):

```
db.a.find().sort({last_edited: 1, _id : 1})
```

As you see, the result is sorted firstly by `last_edited` field and only then by `_id`, if you will do this only by `last_edited` field, you are not in control of the order of `_id` field.

You can have index either on `last_edited` or `last_edited` and `_id` fields.

Comment: The problem with this query is that it only sorts by _id after last_edited has been sorted and only when the last-edited timestamp occurs more than once. I need to sort last_edited and _id **together** meaning that I don't want one field to supersede the other in the sorting process. I essentially want to merge the two fields on sort the documents as if I was sorting on a single field.